# (MySQL) Aggregate functions on MPTT / Nested Set Model

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, nested-sets, mptt

So I'm using MySQL and storing my category structure based on the Nested Set / Modified Pre-Order Tree Traversal model, in a table name "nested_category" which has fields:
`category_id`, `name`, `lft`, `rgt`, `published`

`published` is either 1 or 0... If it's 1 then the category will show upon the live site.  If it's 0 then it won't show on the live site, and more importantly any children of that *unpublished* category won't show on the live site either.

I'm having problems writing a query to list all the categories that have `published=1`, and ignore all categories that are descendants of a category which has `published=0`.

At the moment I'm using:

```
SELECT category_id, lft, rgt FROM nested_category WHERE published = 1
```

I really can't work out how to get it to ignore "child" categories when a parent is "unpublished".

I'm also trying to link this to my "new_products" table which has fields: `product_id`, `name`, `stock`, `price`, `category_id`, so that I can write a query to select all products that have `published=1` and are part of a "published" category.  I have got this far:

```
select @myRight := rgt, @myLeft := lft 
from nested_category where name="ELECTRONICS";

select productId, productName, new_products.category_id, 
price, stock, new_products.published 
from new_products 
inner join ( 
    select category_id, lft, rgt from nested_category 
    where published = 1
) cat 
on new_products.category_id = cat.category_id 
and cat.lft >= @myLeft 
and cat.rgt <= @myRight 
and new_products.published = 1 
order by productName asc
```

Since the above query uses my first query, it doesn't return any "unpublished" categories or products, but it doesn't take into account when a "published" category is a descendant of an "unpublished" category.
Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Little bit improved with depth of nodes:

```
SELECT node.name, node.category_id, node.lft, node.rgt, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_category as node
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT nested_category.category_id, nested_category.lft, nested_category.rgt 
    FROM nested_category, (
        SELECT category_id, lft, rgt 
        FROM nested_category 
        WHERE published = 0
    ) notNodeCat 
    WHERE nested_category.lft >= notNodeCat.lft 
    AND nested_category.rgt <= notNodeCat.rgt ) notNodeCat2
ON notNodeCat2.category_id=node.category_id,
nested_category as parent
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT nested_category.category_id, nested_category.lft, nested_category.rgt 
    FROM nested_category, (
        SELECT category_id, lft, rgt 
        FROM nested_category 
        WHERE published = 0
    ) notParentCat 
    WHERE nested_category.lft >= notParentCat.lft 
    AND nested_category.rgt <= notParentCat.rgt ) notParentCat2
ON notParentCat2.category_id=parent.category_id            
WHERE notNodeCat2.category_id IS NULL AND notParentCat2.category_id IS NULL AND node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after playing around a LOT, I've hacked together something that is working...

```
SELECT nested_category.name, nested_category.category_id, nested_category.lft, nested_category.rgt 
FROM nested_category 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT nested_category.category_id, nested_category.lft, nested_category.rgt 
    FROM nested_category, (
        SELECT category_id, lft, rgt 
        FROM nested_category 
        WHERE published = 0
    ) notCat 
    WHERE nested_category.lft >= notCat.lft 
    AND nested_category.rgt <= notCat.rgt ) notCat2
ON notCat2.category_id=nested_category.category_id 
WHERE notCat2.category_id IS NULL
ORDER BY nested_category.lft ASC
```

It displays all nested_category items that have a `published=1` that are not blocked off by a parent being `published=0`

One thing I do need help with is re-writing it using more left joins, as I hear they're more efficient!